# Increase top and bottom margin FancyBox v2 because of fixed navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm currently working on a website which in future will be responsive. The site is primarily made up of images which in turn load into a FancyBox when clicked. v2 of FancyBox is now responsive and so re-sizes the images etc when screen size changes. As part of my design I have two fixed banners which appear at the top and bottom of the page, see image below:

[image: Fixed position demo]

By default there is a margin around the FancyBox so that it's styled nicely. However, with the fixed positioning that I've added to the banners I need to increase the top and bottom margin. I've looked through the JS source but I can't for the life of me find where I should be adding extra margin. There are all sorts of margins on the transitions etc (which I think is where I'm getting confused).

In theory I just need to add "x" amount of pixels to the margin, where x is the height of the banners. As an aside I'm not sure how I would replicate this in a responsive design, as the banners may be slightly shallower on a mobile. Adding the margin would mean there's a slight gap between the image and the banner, where currently the image goes behind the banner. See the following image for what I'd like it to look like:

[image]

I'd appreciate any thoughts/examples of where this has been done before.

Thanks in advance, Adam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the `margin` API option

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    margin: [120, 60, 20, 60] // top, right, bottom, left
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JZkf2/)**

Comment: This is also useful when you have to create a fancybox with no margins at all.

    `$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0] // top->clockwise.
    });`

Comment: @Luis `margin: 0` does the same job, however works fine for top and bottom margin. Left and right margins may work whether the content can scale or not

Comment: I've found that sometimes fancybox doesn't recognize that syntax.
Especially if you must work with several versions of jQuery in the same project.