# Adding margin to top and bottom of fancybox due to fixed navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've added a margin to the top and bottom of my fancybox images, due to the fact I have a fixed nav bar at the top of my page, using the code I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421351/increase-top-and-bottom-margin-fancybox-v2-because-of-fixed-navigation). I have added this to my jQuery like it said:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    margin: [120, 60, 50, 60] // top, right, bottom, left
});</script>
```

Below this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'fade',
        'transitionOut' :   'fade',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   true
    }); 

    });
    </script>
```

The problem is that when clicking a single image it works the way I want (sits over top of the navigation), but navigating through the images, the next ones which are tall (portrait oriented) sit behind the nav again. I've tried increasing the top margin value but nothing changes.

This is the page with fancybox on it: http://pacificdesignacademy.com/gallerygd.php

Am I doing something wrong here? Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the problem.

Comment: You don't see that when an image is clicked from the thumbnails it sits in front of the nav bar but when navigating through images when opened, they sit behind it again? I've tested this in Firefox, Chrome and Safari and on 2 different computers and it's doing that on all of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18433046/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase top and bottom margin FancyBox v2 because of fixed navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421351/increase-top-and-bottom-margin-fancybox-v2-because-of-fixed-navigation)

Comment: you need a single script so place all the options, including the margins inside the same initialization AND inside the `ready()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'fade',
        'transitionOut' :   'fade',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   true
    }); 

    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    margin: [120, 60, 50, 60] // top, right, bottom, left
});</script>
```

by this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
         'transitionOut': 'fade',
         'speedIn': 600,
         'speedOut': 200,
         'overlayShow': true,
         margin: [120, 60, 50, 60] // top, right, bottom, left
    });
});
</script>
```

**NOTE** : your API options are obsolete (v1.3.4) check the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for the right options of the version you are using

Comment: That worked. I'm a bit new with jQuery as you may have noticed. Thanks so much for your help!